# How to get the last message of a specific user in a specific channel in Slack?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I know how to send messages to a channel by using `chat_postMessage`. Is there a method that retrieves messages from a user in a specfic channel?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this retroactively by using '[conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.list)' and filtering through the messages by user id. You can also do this proactively by using the Events API and subscribing to the `[message][2]` event type. Again you'd have to parse through the event response to get the channel and ser specifics.